# HTML5 drag and drop upload image from another site

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, drag-and-drop

I've succeded in uploading images from my local disk using drag and drop. What I would like to do is drag an image from another website to my dropzone and upload it as if it came from my local disk.

Basically I would like to be able to create a File/Blob object from a url that points to another website. I know how to get the url to the file I have dropped but I don't know how to convert this into a File object.

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Why don't you just send the url of the image to the server and let the server download it?

Comment: That's a valid suggestion. I felt like it would simplify my implementation if I always send a file to be uploaded and not sometimes files and sometimes url. However it's basically about putting complexity in the front end or in the back end.